# facebook pixel events "ViewContent" must have param content_type and content_ids?

Tags: facebook-pixel

I want to add product to facebook catalogs, and I installed facebook pixel and  added required metadata tags on my website, following the instruction. Facebook Pixel Helper does not report any error. But I get the error:

> Missing content_type paramter from ViewContent

on my facebook console. Dose it have to have the param `content_type`?

Answer (score 1):

FB pixel event "ViewContent" has required parameter "content_type"
for example it should looks like this:

[image: Screen from FB pixel helper]

For more information see this FB pixel reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/reference/